# Blocking a react route

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm using a theme named Core-UI and the routing inside the code is a little diffrent. I'm confused on how to block a specific route on app.js that eventually leads to all routes.

I've tried the solutions in the related topic but didn't have luck.

This is from app.js

```
<BrowserRouter>
      <React.Suspense fallback={loading()}>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/" name="Login Page" render={props => <Login {...props} />} />
          <Route exact path="/login" name="Login Page" render={props => <Login {...props} />} />
          <Route exact path="/404" name="Page 404" render={props => <Page404 {...props} />} />
          <Route exact path="/500" name="Page 500" render={props => <Page500 {...props} />} />
          <Route path="/" name="Home" render={props => <DefaultLayout {...props} />} />
        </Switch>
      </React.Suspense>
```

```
<Route path="/" name="Home" render={props => <DefaultLayout {...props} />} />
```

This is the route that I want to block by using localStorage. I've tried this but it failed:

```
<Route path="/" name="Home" render={props => 
            localStorage.getItem('jwtToken') !== null
            ? (
              <DefaultLayout {...props} />
            ) : (
              <Redirect to={{ pathname: "/login" }} />
            )
          } 
/>
```

If any other files are needed I will provide them. Thank you.

Comment: In the first place you have to put your token to `state` and pass it props. If the token changes in your storage, the route won't be rerendered.

Answer (score 0):

based on your code you have two routes for "/" login and home

```
   <Switch>
          <Route path="/" name="Home" render={props => 
            localStorage.getItem('jwtToken') !== null
            ? (
              <DefaultLayout {...props} />
            ) : (
              <Redirect to={{ pathname: "/login" }} />
            )
          } />

          <Route exact path="/login" name="Login Page" render={props => <Login {...props} />} />
          <Route exact path="/login" name="Login Page" render={props => <Login {...props} />} />
          <Route exact path="/404" name="Page 404" render={props => <Page404 {...props} />} />
          <Route exact path="/500" name="Page 500" render={props => <Page500 {...props} />} />
          <Route path="/" name="Home" render={props => <DefaultLayout {...props} />} />
        </Switch>
```

Comment: One of them is "exact path", I also tried your solution it didn't work.